# How to make full month appears on the axis when making graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[I would like to make the month as  1,2,3,4..12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zcbP.png)

I tried to make the month as factor. But it only appears month as 2.5 5 7.5

```
#plot  
ggplot(combine.t.c,aes(x=as.numeric(month))) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_daily_kWh.x, color="red"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_daily_kWh.y,color="blue"))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels =waiver())+
  labs(title  =" Mean kWh/day across the 12 pre-program bills of 2011",
       x      = "Month",
       y      = "Mean_Daily_kWh",
       color="Groups") +
  theme_minimal()+
theme(plot.title    = element_text(face = "bold",   size = 14, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x   = element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.y   = element_text(size=10),
        axis.title.x  = element_text(size=10),
        axis.title.y  = element_text(size=10),
        legend.text   = element_text(size=10),
      legend.title  = element_text(size=10))+
scale_color_manual(labels = c("Participants", "Non-participants"), values = c("red", "blue"))
```

This is my month variable

```
df<-df %>% mutate(month=as.factor(month(bill.date)), 
                  year=year(bill.date))
```

bill_date is

```
2011-01-01
```

Comment: You'll need the column on your x-axis to be `Date` class, then you can use `scale_x_date(date_labels = "%B")`.

Comment: It has the Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Comment: See the first part of my comment - you'll need the column on your x-axis to be `Date` class. If you're unsure about the class of your data or how to make things `Date` class, please post a few rows of sample data using `dput`, like `dput(combine.t.c[1:5, ])`

Comment: From the way you're getting your `month` variable, it looks like `bill.date` is already `Date` class. So you could put that on the x-axis directly, `aes(x = bill.date)`,   or if you want to aggregate everything within a  given month, use `aes(x = floor_date(bill.date, "month"))`.

Comment: Hi I add a group=1 to aes, then it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you might be dealing with different time frames (e.g. 1 month, 5 years, etc.) it's probably easier to convert your dates to a date data-type and then use ggplot's `scale_x_date` to help with identifying sensible breaks and labels. But if you're just working predictably with one year, then a quick hack would be to set your twelve month labels to be the month names.

(Note, one small distinction here is that the months will all look exactly the same width, whereas using a real Date x-axis will have February take up slightly less width than the other months, for instance. See bottom chart for that.)

```
fake_data <- tibble(numeric_month = 1:12,
                        value = sin(numeric_month))

ggplot(fake_data, aes(numeric_month, value)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(fake_data, aes(numeric_month, value)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, minor_breaks = NULL, labels = month.name[1:12])
```

[image]

Here's what it looks like using real dates:

```
fake_data2 <- tibble(dates = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-01"), length.out = 12),
                     value = sin(fake_data$numeric_month))

ggplot(fake_data2, aes(dates, value)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", minor_breaks = NULL, date_labels = "%B")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, I fixed the problem with group=1 added.